# python regular expression with re.split()

Tags: python, regex

i have this string equation:

```
400-IF(3>5,5,5)+34+IF(4>5,5,6)
```

i want to split it by string `'IF(3>5,5,5)',` means `'IF()'` syntax, so here i used two if syntax.

so `re.split()` should give list with length: 2   `['400-', '+34+']`

I made `re` and used as below.

```
re.split('IF[\(][0-9,a-z,A-Z,\$]*[\>|\<|=|/|%|*|^]?(.*)+[\,][0-9,a-z,A-Z,\$]*[\,][0-9,a-z,A-Z,\$]+[\)]', '400-IF(3>5,5,5)+34+IF(4>5,5,6)
')
```

But it is not returning proper answer. What is the mistake in my `re`. I am new in `re`.

Can anyone modify this `re` in python?

Comment: @Robert Grant  i need if() with stuff inside it.

Comment: So when you say it should give `['400-', '+34+']` (which is not the IFs with stuff inside) what do you mean?

Comment: re shoul split it by string like 'IF(3>5,5,5)'

Comment: So in conclusion, you _don't_ need if() with stuff inside, you need the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x="400-IF(3>5,5,5)+34+IF(4>5,5,6)"
print [i for i in re.split(r"IF\([^)]*\)",x) if i]
```

You can simply use this.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> z = '400-IF(3>5,5,5)+34+IF(4>5,5,6)'
>>> ' '.join(re.split(r'IF\(.*?\)',z)).split()
['400-', '+34+']
```